# XPath ignoring closing tags

Tags: java, xml

I have the following line in my xml file that I am trying to parse using XPath. The XML file itself was got by converting a PDF document using PDFtoHTML converter. As you can see, it has not added a closing tag for 
 here. So when I try to execute XPath by trying to capture the textValue of  tag, it throws me an error saying 
 should be followed by a closing tag. How do I overcome this in XPath? Hovewer, when I open the file in a browser, everything is rendered fine in the browser.

```
<DIV style="position:absolute;top:222;left:143">
  <nobr>
    <span class="ft8">Dear Mr. AMIT KUMAR,
      <br>We are happy to enclose<br>31st March, 2011
    </span>
  </nobr>
</DIV>
```

Thanks
Abhishek S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have posted is not XML.  You cannot overcome this with XPath.

After generating the HTML, you could use [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/), to make it into XML, or you could try using a converter that converts PDF to well-formed XML.

Comment: Paul is correct. You cannot confuse between HTML and XML. Html tags are not required to have closing tags such as **<br>** whereas XML obliges you to put a closing tag for each opened tag

Comment: Also HTMLCleaner is very nice for accessing html content as xml: [link](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net)

Comment: Thanks Paul, checking the utility now. Also, if the opening tag is <A ....> and the closing tag is </a> which has a difference in the alphabet case, would the utility make the case same as well - do you know?

Comment: @AbhishekShivkumar It should do, but you'll just have to give it a try, to be sure.